# Python assign dictionary to property

Tags: python, class

i have a class a kind like this:

```
class equipment():
     def __init__(self, l, d):
          self.length = {"desc": "Length of equipment", "val":l, "unit":"ft"}
          self.diameter = {"desc": "Diameter of equipment", "val":d, "unit":"inch"}
```

so im needing a constructor for the properties something line

```
class fisicalProp():
   def __init_(self, d, v, u)
       self.something = {"desc": "Diameter of equipment", "val":d, "unit":"inch"}
```

then i only call

```
class equipment():
         def __init__(self, l, d):
              self.length = fisicalPropertie("Length of equipment",l, "ft"}
              self.diameter = fisicalPropertie("Diameter of equipment", d, "inch"}
```

can you help me to improve my code like that?

Comment: You don't need a *class*, just a *function*: `def fisicalPropertie(desc, val, unit):`, that returns a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you complicate this action? If you use this class for several instances, you don't need to create dict here. Therefore, if are not going to use inheritance, don't need to use () with class definition

```
class equipment:
    def __init__(self, length, len_units, diameter, dia_units):
        self.length = (length, len_units)
        self.diameter = (diameter, dia_units)

eq = equipment(1, "ft", 2, "inch")
print(eq.length, eq.diameter)
```